# Automatic String Matching and Replacement in r

Tags: r, string, string-matching

My dataset has a column, named "Brand" which contains names of washing machine brands. But each brand name is written in 10 different ways. For eg, Whirlpool is written as "wirlpool", "whl", "whp", "WP"; Bosch as "BOSCH", "bosch"; Maytag as "MAY", "MAYTAG" etc. I would like a function that would go through each Brand name and replace, let's say, all "wirlpool", "whl", "whp", "WP" with "Whirlpool". Similarly for Bosch and other Brand names.

*Note: I do not know all the different ways a Brand has been named in the dataset. The levels I mentioned here are a few I came across.*

I can do this manually using grepl in R for each Brand but it's taking a lot of time since the dataset is large. I was wondering if there's an R function that could do it faster. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: do you know before hand what the levels should be? ie `Whirlpool = c("wirlpool", "whl","whp","WP")`?? Can you make a list of that

Comment: I could but the dataset is so large, it's difficult to go through every row.

Comment: Its not going through every row. Check the answer provided

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have:

```
 vec <- c("wirlpool", "whl","whp","WP", "BOSCH", "bosch","MAY", "MAYTAG")
```

We could use:

```
lst <- list(
         Whirlpool = c("wirlpool", "whl","whp","WP"),
         Bosch = c("BOSCH", "bosch"),
         Maytag = c("MAY", "MAYTAG")
 )

forcats::fct_recode(vec, !!!do.call(set_names, unname(stack(lst))))
[1] Whirlpool Whirlpool Whirlpool Whirlpool Bosch     Bosch     Maytag    Maytag   
Levels: Bosch Maytag Whirlpool
```

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu for your solution. I do not know all the levels of Whirlpool, Bosch, Maytag or any other Brand name. The ones I put in my question are a few cases I came across. There may be many more. My dataset contains ~22k rows.

Comment: @DebasmitaDas then how do you decide/ determine that whl or whp is Whirlpool? What is the criterion? Is it because it starts with `W`?

Comment: Starts with W, also is similar to Whirlpool. I do not know any other washer that starts with W. I am guessing whl/whp means Whirlpool. I did not enter the Brand names, other people did.

Comment: @DebasmitaDas unless you know a method that can extract all the `Whirlpool` acronyms or synonyms there is no way this can be coded. If we say all that start with `W` will be `whirlpool`, all that start with `B` will be `Bosch` then that is doable etc

Comment: @ Onyambu Do you think LCS Algorithm can be helpful here?

Comment: @DebasmitaDas not at all. You said you have  large dataset, and due to the high order of LCS , it means the data with explode hence making it unreasonable to find the LCS. Although you could try it out. You will have to include an example of the dataset